# SQL request with an array of arguments

Tags: php, mysql, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a problem with a SQL(dql) request,
I have a table with Books(Media), a table with categories, and a table who associate the two: CategoryAffiliation (a book can have multiple categories)

In the Client side, i can choose to search for books by checking multiple categories. Then the client send a array of categories to the server and he must return the books who have at least one of those categories.

```
$books = [];
if (isset($data['categories'])) {
    foreach ($data['categories'] as $key => $value){
        $query = $em->createQuery("SELECT m
                                   FROM AppBundle:Media m, AppBundle:Category c, AppBundle:CategoryAffiliation mc
                                   WHERE m.idMedia = mc.idMedia
                                   AND mc.idCategory = :key
                                   GROUP by m.idMedia"
        )->setParameter('key',$key);
        $result = $query->getResult();
        foreach ($result as $book) {
            array_push($books, $book);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my solution for now but this is not great, i can't ORDER BY the result..
I receive an array of duplicates books, and then in the client side I merge them to delete the duplicates.

I am searching a way to have a single request to fetch all the data at once

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have access to my stuff to test it but this could do it. I'm just not sure how setParameter will handle the fact that I put `'` inside the string. I think that you will need to get the raw information. I can't remember how symfony and doctrine manage that, it's been too long ;)

If you can't find an other way, you could build it in the string directly... which I don't really recommend.

```
$query = $em->createQuery("SELECT m
                           FROM AppBundle:Media m, AppBundle:Category c, AppBundle:CategoryAffiliation mc
                           WHERE m.idMedia = mc.idMedia
                                 AND mc.idCategory IN (:key)
                           GROUP by m.idMedia"
        )->setParameter('key',implode("','",array_keys($data['categories'])));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have seen that kind of workaround but people say it is a possible SQL injection breach! Will keep you updated :)

Comment: I have done the request in pure SQL directly in PHPmyadmin and it's working! But not in Php

Comment: It's sure that you have a risk of SQL Injection if someone do some manipulations, you may need to check depending on the situation. For an open web app, maybe each key should be escaped before to be sure you don't open a door. When you look in debug, you can see how the query has been executed with doctrine, it may be only missing quotes or something like that.